# Are these true for a martingale? $E\left[ \frac{X_{n+1}}{X_n} \right] = 1, E\left[ \frac{X_{n+2}}{X_n} \right] = 1 $

Tags: expected-value, martingales

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+}$
be a martingale, $X_n(\omega) \neq 0$, and $X_{n+1}/X_n, X_{n+2}/X_n \in L^1 (n \in \mathbb{Z}_+)$

Do the following hold for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$?

$E\left[ \frac{X_{n+1}}{X_n} \right] = 1, E\left[ \frac{X_{n+2}}{X_n} \right] = 1 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(X_{n+m}|\mathcal F_m)=X_m$. This implies $E(\frac  {X_{n+m}} {X_m}|\mathcal F_m)=1$ provided $\frac {X_{n+m}} {X_m}$ is integrable. Taking expectation on both  sides we get $E(\frac  {X_{n+m}} {X_m})=1$ .

Comment: So you're using that $\frac{1}{X_m}$ is measurable in $\mathcal{F_m}$, right?

Comment: @Kay Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you for the help!